# Command to insert into with select

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table:

```
create table Student(name varchar(20), surname varchar(20), age int);
```

First, insert into table this fields:

```
insert into Student values ("Jhon", "Smith", null);
insert into Student values ("Mark", "William", null);
```

Now, how do I insert age=28 where name = 'Jhon'??

Comment: Tip : this is not an insert, but an update...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [UPDATE](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdev.mysql.com%2Fdoc%2Frefman%2F5.0%2Fen%2Fupdate.html&ei=uuirU8KPObPL0AWe5oGICA&usg=AFQjCNGVsZPXuo2367dgxMLfQjgy7VivQw&sig2=bvQnqF9s7LV2on5RzstNKg&bvm=bv.69837884,d.d2k) as below :

```
UPDATE Student SET age = 28 WHERE name = "Jhon";
```

**Notice :** *It will change age of all people who `name = "Jhon"`*

It's far better to define [Primary Key (ID)](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0CCUQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdev.mysql.com%2Fdoc%2Frefman%2F5.5%2Fen%2Foptimizing-primary-keys.html&ei=xumrU_qnJur60gXE-YGABQ&usg=AFQjCNFqRq93Jd9tqU_v_8pd5li3T-U88Q&sig2=DA9it6S5tAgXw3WHeIBJCw&bvm=bv.69837884,d.d2k) for a column to perform commands for specific ID.

Answer (score 0):

`UPDATE Student SET age = 28 WHERE name = 'Jhon'`

But please take care of your referetial integrity!

Those data structure without any unique ID is not a safe way to store a great amount of data.

Answer (score 0):

update student
set age = 28
where name "john"

you may want to read a beginners guide to sql to help you along.